# Finding the sum of a series from nth partial sum formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

The formula I obtained was:

$$ s_n = \frac {1(1-(-2)^n)}{3} $$

for the series

$$ 1 -2+4-8+ \cdots + (-1)^{n-1}2^{n-1} + \cdots $$

If the formula is correct, how do I find the sum as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Such a sum exists only if the sequence of partial sums of the series converges. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oh, so the sequence diverges...And we tell that not from the equation but the sequence itself?

Comment: Let's be clear about which sequence is which: There is a sequence whose $n$th term is $(-2)^{n-1}$, and there is the sequence of partial sums, whose $n$th term is $s_n = \dfrac{1 - (-2)^n} 3$.  Convergence of the _series_, i.e. the sum of infinitely many terms, is the same as convergence of the sequence of partial sums, the second sequence here.  A necessary condition for that is convergence of the first sequence, whose $n$th term is $(-2)^{n-1}$, to zero. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Excuse me for not fully understanding: So as the nth term of the first sequence does not come to zero, the sequence diverges? I'm getting confused by what you provided.

Comment: If the $n$th term of the FIRST sequence does not approach zero, then the SECOND sequence, the sequence of partial sums, diverges. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: prove by induction that your sum is given by $$\frac{1}{9} \left(3 n+(-2)^{n+1}+2\right)$$